# SQL display MIN() column with other columns displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a report where I need to display a student id, the score and the lowest date/time that the score was filed. The table will have multiple scores per student across multiple days.

The problem I am having (using the sample code below) is that I am getting a new row for every score, instead of just one line per student showing the student id, score and date.

### sample source table columns

student_id |
score |
score_date

```
select tests.student_id
      ,tests.score
      ,min(score_date)
from tests

group by tests.student_id
        ,tests.score
```

Comment: use `row_number()` window function to get the earliest date

Comment: which score were you expecting to see next to the studentID/lowest date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `row_number()` for this one.

```
select * from (
    select t1.student_id
          ,t1.score
          ,row_number() over (partition by t1.student_id order by t1.score_date) rn 
          ,t1.score_date
    from tests t1) t
where t.rn = 1
```

There is also one trick by using `correlated subquery`.

```
select student_id
    , min(score_date) score_date
    , (select top 1 score from tests where score_date = min(t.score_date) and student_id = t.student_id) as score
from tests t
group by student_id
```

or if you are using **sql server 2012** and higher versions. You can maximize the use of `first_value()` function.

```
select distinct first_value(student_id) over (partition by student_id order by score_date)
    , first_value(score_date) over (partition by student_id order by score_date)
    , first_value(score) over (partition by student_id order by score_date)
from tests t
group by student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT student_id, score, score_date
FROM tests T 
INNER JOIN (SELECT student_id, Min(score_date) AS score_date FROM tests) X 
ON T.student_id = X.student_id AND T.score_date = X.score_date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the dates per student when they had their lowest score?

Then the window function [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) comes to mind.  Sorted by ascending `score`.

```
WITH CTE_STUDENT_SCORES AS
(
  SELECT student_id, score, score_date
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY score ASC) AS StudentAscendingScoreRank
  FROM tests
)
SELECT student_id, score, score_date
FROM CTE_STUDENT_SCORES
WHERE StudentAscendingScoreRank = 1
ORDER BY student_id, score_date
```

If only the latest score_date with the student lowest score is needed?
Then one could limit on ROW_NUMBER instead.
Sorted by ascending score and descending score_date.

```
WITH CTE_STUDENT_SCORES AS
(
  SELECT student_id, score, score_date
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY score ASC, score_date DESC) AS StudentAscendingScoreRownum
  FROM tests
)
SELECT student_id, score, score_date
FROM CTE_STUDENT_SCORES
WHERE StudentAscendingScoreRownum = 1
ORDER BY score_date DESC, student_id;
```